# Use Android Alarm Manager to do a specific task

Tags: android, process, background

Is it possible to use Android Alarm manager to trigger a specific task at a specific time?

The log i got:

```
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate       activity ComponentInfo{com.example.timeevent/com.example.timeevent.MainActivity}:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.timeevent.MainActivity
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.timeevent.MainActivity
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
03-13 22:18:20.219: E/AndroidRuntime(1140):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure is, take a look at this fairly straight forward tutorial: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Comment: I'm getting and error when i run it... Please take a look, i updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Although, it is not the AlarmManager itself that executes the specific task at a specific time, but the receiver for the alarm.

After you have implemented the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), that sends an intent at a specific time, you will have to implement an alarm receiver, that extends the class [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and executes the code for the desired task.

For more thoughts on how to set alarms, read the tutorial on [scheduling repeating alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) on the Android Developer site.

Edit: Your log says it: the activity `com.example.timeevent.MainActivity` was not found. Did you rename it? Also don't forget to register your activity as a receiver in the AppManifest.